# Object - checking if field exists

Tags: jquery, hasownproperty

I have an object with following markup :

```
Object {workout: Object}
   workout: Object
   1/12/2015: Array[3]
       0: "workoutTitle0"
       1: "workoutTitle1"
       2: "workoutTitle2"
    2/12/2015: Array[3]
    3/12/2015: Array[3]
    4/12/2015: Array[3]
    5/12/2015: Array[3]
    6/12/2015: Array[3]
    7/12/2015: Array[3]
```

I want to check if for example the field 10/12/2015 exists - if exists I want to load array that this field is holding, if not create new empty array for that field.

I tried this code but I get false everytime, even when field do not exist:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    var prop = '10/12/2015'
    for( prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here if JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/x9dnwgwc/3/

Comment: If you're interacting with the object in memory, it's not JSON, it's just an object. JSON is a *textual* notation for data exchange.

Comment: Your browser has a fully-featured debugger built into it: Use the menus to open the debugger, or on most browsers it's F12 and/or Ctrl+Shift+I (Cmd+Shift+I on Macs). The debugger will let you execute your code a line at a time ("single-step" through your code) and let you see what's in your variables as you step through. Very useful for understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to check if for example the field 10/12/2015 exists

You're working too hard, it's just:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('10/12/2015')) {
    // It exists in the object itself
}
```

...for an "own" property, or

```
if ('10/12/2015' in obj) {
    // It exists in the object or one of its prototypes
}
```

...for a property that's it's own **or** it inherits from a prototype.

> I tried this code but I get false everytime, even when field do not exist:
>
> ```
> function isEmpty(obj) {
>     var prop = '10/12/2015'
>     for( prop in obj) {
>         if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
>             return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Your

```
var prop = '10/12/2015';
```

line declares the `prop` variable, and assigns it the value '10/12/2015';  but then you **immediately** overwrite that value with:

```
for( prop in obj) {
```

The first thing the `for-in` loop will do is overwrite the value of `prop`.

What your loop was really doing was checking to see if the object had any "own" properties (if so, it returned `false`) or only properties it inherited from its prototype(s) (if so, it returned 'true').

Comment: Checked again , and still something is messed up

https://jsfiddle.net/x9dnwgwc/4/

It returns true , even if the prop exists in object ...

Comment: @marcinf2: You're looking on `jsonObj`. It's not on `jsonObj`, it's on `jsonObj.workout`: https://jsfiddle.net/x9dnwgwc/6/ (And again, just as a side note, JSON isn't involved there. It's just an object.)

Comment: @marcinf2: That `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { return false; } else { return true; }` can, of course, be written `return !obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);`